# Is this printf format possible (left-justify sign and no sign on zero)?

Tags: c, string, formatting, printf, string-formatting

I'm trying to use printf to get the following programmatic output:

```
- 20
- 15
- 10
-  5
   0
+  5
+ 10
+ 15
+ 20
```

The key specifications are:

- The field width is always 4
- The sign is always left-justified
- The number is always right-justified
- The zero has no sign

So far I have not been able to come up with a printf statement that will give me the desired results. The closest I have is:

```
for(int i = -20; i <= 20; i+=5)
{
    printf("%-+4d \n", i);
}
```

which produces:

```
-20
-15
-10
-5
+0
+5
+10
+15
+20
```

Is there a way to do this without having to do any cumbersome string manipulation?

Comment: What should the output be if `i` is outside the range [-999... + 999]?  Or is that a "don't care"?

Comment: In this application, `i` is only in the range [-20, 20]. However, for others who may view this question, noting the valid range of `i` is important for a valid answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
printf("%c%3d\n", i>0 ? '+' : i<0 ? '-' : ' ', abs(i));
```

Note the above fails for `INT_MIN`, but that shouldn't be an issue since your values are only expected to be less than 1000 in magnitude.

Comment: Darn beat me by 1 minute and got it in one line. +1

Comment: @Tyler, Well, there was a bug I found because of your answer. (I thought `0` was suppose to be `+0`. Fixed.)

Comment: Oops, I didn't run yours.

Comment: `i = INT_MIN;` -> boom.

Comment: @EOF, Mentioned the limitation in the answer. I don't have a portable solution that works for `INT_MIN` too. Switching to `llabs` (and adjusting the format specifier) should do the trick, but `long long int` doesn't appear to be guaranteed to be longer than `int`.

Comment: @ikegami True that printing `|INT_MIN|` in a _highly_ portable fashion is tricky.

Answer (score 3):

A simple one-liner, not much different than others, yet with a nice look-up to a `"- +"` string.

```
printf("%c%3d\n", "- +"[i >= 0 + i > 0], abs(i));
```

---

To handle values outside the [-999 ... + 999] range and especially the pesky `i = INT_MIN` where the  `-i` is *undefined behavior*, the code could use:

```
printf("%c%3u\n", "- +"[i >= 0 + i > 0], (i < 0) ? 0u - i: 0u + i);
// or
printf("%c%3lld\n", "- +"[i >= 0 + i > 0], llabs(i));
```

---

For a pedantic full range solution

```
// Buffer size = iceil(bit-width * log2(10)) + sign + null character
#define INT_BUF_SIZE (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)*31/100 + 3)

int print_int(int x) {
  char buf[INT_BUF_SIZE*2];
  sprintf(buf, "%+d", x);
  int width = 4;
  return printf("%c%*s\n", x ? buf[0] : ' ', width - 1, buf + 1);
}
```

#### Example output

```
- 20
   0
+ 20
+2147483647
-2147483648
```

Comment: Note that while this is clever, modern C++ compilers tend to issue warnings on use of a bool expression in an integer context (which is fair, as it's usually a mistake).  The shenanigans required to disable that warning (either with pragmas or by adding casts to show intent) make this less attractive.

Comment: @Miral As post and answer are C and not C++, do you find the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288085/is-this-printf-format-possible-left-justify-sign-and-no-sign-on-zero/46288490?noredirect=1#comment105834204_46288490) with a C  compiler?  There is no `bool` expression here. `i >= 0` is an `int` one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = -20; i <= 20; i += 5){
    if(i == 0){
        printf("%4d\n", i);
    }
    else{
        (i > 0) ? printf("+%3d\n", i) : printf("-%3d\n", -i);
    }
}
```

It is ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = -20; i <= 20; i+=5) {
    if( i < 0 ) 
        printf("-%3d \n", -i);
    else if(i == 0)
        printf("  0 \n");
    else
        printf("+%3d \n", i);
}
```

Comment: You should use `else` to avoid unnecessary checks. /// `abs(i)` could be simplified to `-i`. /// `printf(" %3d \n", i);` could be simplified to `printf("   0 \n");`